# HTML5shiv does not work properly on IE8

Tags: asp.net, iis, html5shiv

I try to use HTML5shiv (download from google) to format my menu to horizontal menu! The problem is when I call my website using localhost, the menu works perfect. But when I call my website using ip (example 192.168.1.1/menu.aspx), the menu does not format correctly. Apparently I need to be able to call website using ip instead of localhost, for obvious reason :)

First image is what i want. Second one is what it appears.
[Correct Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdzdm.jpg)
[Incorrect Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAk3G.jpg).

```
  <%@ page Language="VB" CodeFile="test_menu.aspx.vb" Inherits="ddd" %>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
     <meta lang="th" charset="windows-874" />
      <!--[if lte IE 9]>
     <script src="/CSS/html5_2.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        nav{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin-left:30px;border-radius:5px; width:90%;margin-right: 0px;
        }
     nav ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px;} 
     nav ul li{list-style-type:none; display:inline-block;  margin:0 0 0 -3px}
     nav ul li a{ display:block; color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none; text-     transform:uppercase; padding:10px 25px;  background:#2429E8; border-right:solid 1px #fff;text-wrap:none;}
     nav ul li:hover>a{ background:#49A3FF}
     nav ul li:first-child a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;text-wrap:none;}
     nav ul li:last-child a{border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;}
/*...First-Level...*/
     nav ul li ul li:first-child a{border-top:solid 5px #fff;text-wrap:none;}
     nav ul li ul li:last-ch`enter code here`ild a{border-bottom:solid 5px #fff;text-wrap:none;}
     nav ul li ul{position:absolute; display:none; /*width:340px;*/ margin:0;text-wrap:none;white-space:nowrap}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:block;text-wrap:none;white-space:nowrap;}
nav ul li ul li{display:block; position:relative; border:none;text-wrap:none;}
nav ul li ul li a{ border-bottom:solid 1px #f4f4f4; border-right:5px solid #fff; border-left:5px solid #fff; border-radius:0px!important; background:#2429E8;  margin:0px; padding:5px; text-wrap:none;}

/*...Second-Level...*/
nav ul li:hover ul ul{display:none}
nav ul li ul li:hover>ul{display:block}
/*...Third-Level...*/
nav ul li ul li ul{display:none; background:#2429E8; position:absolute; top:-10%; left:145px; width:140px;}

        .auto-style1 {
            width: 90%;
            border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">
           <tr>
                <td><nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Treaty</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Create New Treaty</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Add Reinsurer to Treaty</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Change Treaty</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Change Reinsurer to Treaty</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">Faculatative</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>    
                </td>
                <td>

    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <div>
        <br /><br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using .net 4, IIS7 run on windows7 and IE8. The point is why using IP does not work while using "localhost" does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the images, This seems to be a Browser specific Problem and NOT an HTML5shiv Problem.

Please check which `Document Mode` Your IE8 is running in. If it is IE8 then its some other error. 
If it's something else than IE8 please add this `meta` tag as the first element of the `<head>` Tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: Wow!! This work perfect! Anyway I change to asp.net Menu Control a while ago. Thanks a lot!